# Import Ant-build into Gradle Task

Tags: java, gradle, ant, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am working on migration on Ant to Gradle. Currently I have 2 build.xml files which created 2 different .ear files. 
Instance buildA.xml is depends on buildB.xml and I need to build BuildB.xml separately.  I only have one build.gradle and I tried importing 2 build using ant.importBuild 'A.xml'
ant.importBuild 'B.xml'
So, I am not not able to build the buildB.xml and even I do its getting the same set of JARs as BuildA. Should I create anoth build.gradle to make it separate?? Please give me suggestions if you have any idea. 
FYI- buildA is subset of buildB

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have naming collisions of ant target names in the ant build files you can import them with a “transformer” closure:

```
ant.importBuild('buildA.xml') { antTargetName ->
    'a-' + antTargetName
}

ant.importBuild('buildB.xml') { antTargetName ->
    'b-' + antTargetName
}
```